# Tyre suddenly gets tilted

Tags: wheels

Hey guys i have a simple cycle .It do not have gears in it but today while cycling , my rear tyre suddenly gets tilted towards right hand side . One of the , the upper side is tilted towards right and the other side bottom part is tilted towards left hand  ..plz help me

Comment: Is it the tire or the whole wheel?

Answer (score 2):

The wheel nuts on the ends of the axle may have been a bit loose allowing the axle to shift a bit in the frame. Try loosening both nuts with a spanner, centre the wheel carefully, then tighten the nuts again (need to be good and tight). Then re-check that the wheel is running correctly.

Comment: One should make sure the wheel is pulled all the way rearward before centering and tightening.

Comment: Yes - and this should leave the chain without slack - (but not crazily taut either).